# How do I retrieve values back values from passed object?

Tags: java, generics, object

I'm trying to insert different data types into linked list. The problem is that after I insert data I don't know how to read values back when I display my data.

So how to retrieve the values in this kind of order:

```
List (first-->last): {brand1, 11,111}, {brand2, 22,222}
List (last-->first): {brand2, 22,222}, {brand1, 11,111}
```

The output I get represent name of the object and then address of  the object:

```
List (first-->last): Milk@1f5205c Milk@1fb069 
List (last-->first): Milk@1fb069 Milk@1f5205c
```

This is my object class:

```
class Milk <T>
{
    String brand;
    double size;
    double price;

    Milk(String a, double b, double c)
    {
        brand = a;
        size = b;
        price = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your `Milk` class a Generic? Beyond that, you would either need to create getters in the Milk class to retrieve the values or override `toString()` to print something meaningful. You also don't show what a `Link<T>` but I'm guessing you're just passing `Milk` objects contained in them to `System.println()`

Comment: @Brian Roach, I need my program to accept any data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override your Milk class's `toString` method so that it uses a custom version instead of falling back on `Object`'s implementation.

In your case, this would probably be as easy as throwing this in to your `Milk` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return brand;
}
```

Comment: Also, like Brian said, your Milk class does not need to be generic (it does not need the <T>).

Comment: I understand. The purpose of my code is to learn bit of generic types.

Comment: Try implementing an `ArrayList`. You'll learn a lot more about Generics doing that than you would just tacking on a pointless <T> to a random class.